# Do balls of finite radius have finite volume?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, volume

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. For a point $p\in M$ and $r\ge0$, let $B_r(p)$ denote the closed ball of radius $r$ around $p$, i.e. the ball consisting of all points in $M$ that have distance less than or equal to $r$ from $p$ in the metric induced by the Riemannian metric. Do such balls always have finite volume? If not, what is a counter-example?

In case such a ball is compact, it necessarily has finite volume, because sufficiently small coordinate charts have finite volume and the ball could then be covered with finitely many of these. If $M$ is complete, the Hopf-Rinow theorem implies that these balls are compact, so a counter-example would have to be incomplete, but I don't know anything further.

Comment: This is interesting, I wonder if the bounds offered by Kodani at least shows that there is a lower bound? https://projecteuclid.org › euclid.kmj
AN ESTIMATE ON THE VOLUME OF METRIC BALLS 1 ... - Project Euclid

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Consider the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ and a metric of the form $g=dr^2+f^2(r)d\theta^2$, where $f$ is a smooth positive function chosen so that $g$ is well behaved at the origin. The set $B_r(0)$ is the same as in the Euclidean metric, since radial geodesics are unchanged, but the volume differs; a simple computations shows
$$
\operatorname{vol}(B_r(0))=2\pi\int_0^{\min(1,r)}f(\rho)d\rho
$$
Thus $\operatorname{vol}(B_1(0))$ can be made to diverge by choosing a suitable $f$ which diverges as $r\to 1^-$.

I haven't computed it, but I suspect the curvature of such a metric also diverges as $r\to 1^-$, and that this specific behavior can be controlled by a lower bound on the curvature.

**Edit:**

Without any kind of completeness assumptions, one can construct even more pathological counterexamples. Here's one which is flat and simply connected.

Let $S$ be the universal cover of the punctured Euclidean plane the with projection $\pi:S\to\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0\}$ (equipped with the pullback metric), and let $\rho:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be the "radial" function defined by $\rho(p)=\|\pi(p)\|$. The set $\{p\in S:\rho(p)<r\}$ is an open submanifold of infinite volume, since it is an infinite-sheeted cover of a punctured open ball. Additionally, one can show by constructing paths which loop arbitrarily tightly around the origin that $d(p,q)\le\rho(p)+\rho(q)$. Thus, any ball $B_r(p)$ in $S$ with $r>\rho(p)$ has infinite volume.

With this kind of local pathological behavior in mind, I don't think the size of geodesic balls can be controlled by bounding the curvature alone.

Comment: A lower bound on Ricci curvature would suffices (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bishop%E2%80%93Gromov_inequality))

Comment: @ArcticChar: I am not so sure since in the BG inequality one usually assumes completeness.

Comment: @ArcticChar That inequality requires the existence of minimizing geodesics, so that $B_r(p)\subseteq \exp_p(B_r(0))$ (completeness is sufficient). I've added another counterexample which illustrates what can go wrong.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding this intuitively. It feels like a ball should have finite (Riemannian) volume. Consider a Riemannian manifold $M$ and pick a fixed point $p\in M$. Clearly, for _sufficiently small_ radii $r$, the ball $B_r(p)$ is compact (and homeomorphic to a standard ball) and has finite Riemannian volume. So we can consider the supremum (least upper bound) $Q$ of all radii such that the volume of $B_r(p)$ is still finite. This $Q$ depends of the chosen $p$, of course. Your answer claims $Q$ can be finite. Does this radius $Q(p)$ have a name?

Comment: @MoisheKohan We need only the existence of minimizing geodesic, which is the case in the radial symmetric case.

Comment: @ArcticChar: Yes; I thought you mean in general.

Comment: The second example is fantastic, thanks, but I haven't quite figured out the first one yet. Sorry if I'm missing something silly, but how are we making sense of $dr^2$ at the origin?

Comment: @Thorgott $dr$ isn't defined at the origin, strictly speaking, but we can choose $f$ so that $g$ extends smoothly to the origin, e.g. by setting $f(r)=r^2$ for $r\in(0,\epsilon)$. You can write $g$ in Cartesian coordinates if you want to avoid this subtlety.

Comment: That makes sense. I was trying to do a computation to convince myself that the lines through the origin are still geodesics, but now it seems to me that if we choose $f$ such that $\int_0^rf$ diverges as $r\rightarrow1^-$, then the length of the straight line from $0$ to $rx$ ($x$ a unit vector) will similarly blow up as $r\rightarrow1^-$. It's likely my computations are wrong, but I don't understand why the balls in this example are the same as in the Euclidean plane. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Thorgott $f$ only modifies lengths perpendicular to the radial geodesics, since $d\theta(\partial_r)=0$ and thus $g(\partial_r,\partial_r)=1$ independent of $f$. It's the length of the geodesic circles around the origin that diverges.

Comment: The first example isn't a complete manifold - radial geodesics leave the manifold in finite time. Also, the proof of the Bishop-Gromov inequality doesn't require completeness. The first example has curvature diverging to $-\infty$.