# Is averaging over a ball smooth?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-integration, average

Let $M = (M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, and for $f \in L_{loc}^1(M)$ (with respect to the volume measure $V$), write
$$A_{x, r} f : = V(B(x, r))^{-1} \int_{B(x, r)} f \; \mathrm{d} V .$$
My question: Under what conditions on $f$ is the function $X \times \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $(x, r) \mapsto A_{x, r} f$ a $C^1$ function? I've tried a few "toy examples" like when $M = \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}^2$ where this average admits an explicit formula, but I haven't been able to extrapolate to any greater generality. I admittedly don't know a lot about this area, so any relevant references would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: $\mathbb{R}^+ : = (0, \infty)$

EDIT 2: Thorgott alerted me to[this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3994809/do-balls-of-finite-radius-have-finite-volume) which pointed out that this function needn't be well-defined for large $r$, since even balls of finite radius can have infinite volume in the right metric. I'm okay limiting my attention to the case where $M$ is compact, which if I'm not mistaken should alleviate this issue.

Comment: Locally, you should be able to introduce coordinates and write down an explicit enough formula for $A_{x,r}f$ in these coordinates to apply differentiation under the integral sign to argue that this function is differentiable. Note, however, that the function is in general not defined on all of $X\times\mathbb{R}^{+}$, but only on a neighborhood of $X\times\{0\}$ in $X\times\mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @Thorgott I'm not sure how I'd go about writing this formula in general, since by my understanding, a Riemannian manifold isn't locally isometric to Euclidean space. As for your comment about definition, if I take $f$ to be locally integrable (which every smooth function is), then yes, the function $A_{x, r}$ should be globally defined. Also, I'd assumed this was clear from context, but I use $\mathbb{R}^+$ here to mean $(0, \infty)$, which doesn't include $0$.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, trying to write down a nice local formula is not as easy on second thought as you have no control over how the balls behave under an arbitrary chart (balls centered around any particular point can be nicely controlled by picking normal coordinates, but we want our points to vary...). I don't have an immediate fix for this.

Comment: I do believe the function can be continuously extended to $r=0$, essentially by the fundamental theorem of calculus (taking the limit of averages over balls of radius $r$ as $r\rightarrow0$ returns the value of $f$ at the point; admittedly I'm only thinking about nice enough functions at the moment). The issue is in the other direction, namely these integrals have no reason to converge for arbitrary balls, only for sufficiently small ones. [Even the balls themselves need not have finite volume](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3994809/do-balls-of-finite-radius-have-finite-volume).

Comment: @Thorgott Does assuming the manifold to be compact resolve this issue? Either way, edited the OP. I didn't realize that could happen.

Comment: Smooth and $C^1$ are not the same.

Comment: Yeah, on a compact manifold, the function is at least be defined everywhere.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I'm aware. That's why I clarify the question in the actual body.